# Why does RangeReplaceableCollection require an empty initialiser?

Tags: swift, swift3

`RangeReplaceableCollection` requires the implementation of `init()`. This empty initialiser seems to be used in the default implementations of `init(_:)`, `init(repeating:count:)` and `removeAll(keepingCapacity:)`, of which the latter should also be implementable with `removeSubrange(_:)`.

Why are these three initialisers part of `RangeReplaceableCollection`?

How I ran into this: I was making a collection that behaves like an array, but can be subscripted using any generic index that conforms to `Strideable`. It's declared like this:

```
public struct AnyIndexArray
<Index: Strideable, Element where Index.Stride == Int> {

    private var elements: [Element]
    public var startIndex: Index

    public init<S: Sequence where S.Iterator.Element == Element>
        (elements: S, startIndex: Index) {
        self.elements = Array(elements)
        self.startIndex = startIndex
    }

}
```

Since the underlying array conforms to `RangeReplaceableCollection`, it would make sense to also conform `AnyIndexArray` to this protocol. However, I can't provide an empty initialiser because at the very least a `startIndex` is needed. If I implement the empty initialiser anyways and just put `fatalError()` in its body, everything works fine - except for the three initialisers and `removeAll`.

What is it about `RangeReplaceableCollection` that it needs an empty initialiser, while `Collection` doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

"An empty initializer - is useful in generic functions, as it allows a function to create new empty collections of the same type" as objc.io "Advanced Swift" book mentions.

For me it sounds like implementation should be optional, but worth discussing it in swift-evolution group.

In your case why startIndex couldn't have default value 0 ?

**Addition:**

Actually it was already discussed here https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-users/Week-of-Mon-20160704/002510.html

Comment: I also read that Advanced Swift snippet, and I thought it was quite unsatisfactory. It doesn't really explain why the empty initialiser is a good fit for `RangeReplaceableCollection`, rather than another one. It can be useful, sure, but it should still make sense in that particular protocol.

Comment: `startIndex` can't have a default value of 0 in my example, because I was allowing any `Strideable` index, not just integers. :)

Comment: I also read the evolution thread (in fact, I initiated it). I think I'll put a proposal forward to move `init()` into a separate protocol.